# Powershell select a specific value

Tags: powershell

Hi sorry I'm not a scripting guy, I think my problem is quite simple but I can't find the answer.

I do that:

```
$i = Get-ClusterResource "Cluster IP Address" | get-clusterparameter | Select -Property value
```

And get that:

```
Value
-----
Cluster Network 2
10.32.32.36
255.255.252.0
2
0
0
255.255.252.0
1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
255.255.255.255
0.0.0.0
255.0.0.0
```

But the only information I need is the ip "10.32.32.36" so I tried:

```
$i = Get-ClusterResource "Cluster IP Address" | get-clusterparameter | Select -Property value | Select-String -SimpleMatch "10."
```

But then I get `$i = @{Value=10.32.32.36}`

I don't know why it adds the `@{value=xxxx}` how to remove it and only have the IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the cluster address you should get just the `Address` cluster parameter:

```
$i = Get-ClusterResource "Cluster IP Address" `
       | Get-ClusterParameter Address `
       | select Value
```

The above command will return an object with a property `Value` that holds the IP address. If you want just the actual IP address, use this instead:

```
$i = (Get-ClusterResource "Cluster IP Address" `
       | Get-ClusterParameter Address).Value
```

Answer (score 1):

if the ip is always the second value you can use:

```
$i =  (Get-ClusterResource "Cluster IP Address" | get-clusterparameter | 
     Select -expand value )[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Select-String is not designed to operate on objects, it designed to operate on text (files). The tool in PowerShell designed for filtering objects is Where-Object cmdlet:

```
$i = Get-ClusterResource "Cluster IP Address" | 
    get-clusterparameter | 
    Where-Object { $_.Value -like '10.*' } |
    Foreach-Object { $_.Value }
```

Another thing is the fact that you want the value, not custom object with single property (that's what `select -property value` will create). Thus - you can either use `-expand` parameter on `Select-Object` or use `Foreach-Object` cmdlet instead.

Answer (score 0):

Select-string returns MatchInfo objects.  To get just the value of the matched line, you need to select out just the value of the "Line" property:

```
$i = Get-ClusterResource "Cluster IP Address" |
 get-clusterparameter |
 Select -Property value |
 Select-String -SimpleMatch "10." |
 Select -ExpandProperty Line
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem with an office365 online command, where I wanted to catch just the value into a variable,  I did this:

```
$displayname = get-mailbox $whataccount | select displayname
```

And, just like you, I received this:

```
"@{DisplayName=Bob Newhart}
```

This is what I did to get just the value I wanted:

```
$displayname = get-mailbox $whataccount | select displayname
$displayname = $displayname.displayname
```

Now the variable contains only this:  `Bob Newhart`

But this is basically the same as what Ansgar Wiechers says in his answer.