# Using Powershell, how do I get the Azure VIP of a given Service Name?

Tags: powershell, azure

I am following this tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn376546.aspx

At this point:

```
Step 4: Create the availability group listener
```

We are told to enter the public VIP of the cloud service.

I want to get this programatically using Powershell.

I've seen this answer:

[azure-powershell-get-public-virtual-ip-of-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857495/azure-powershell-get-public-virtual-ip-of-service)

However, my service has multiple IPs and so a list is returned.

Is it possible to use Get-AzureService to get the IP address rather than the workaround of asking a VM for the EndPoint?

Alternatively, is it possible to get the first IP address in the list returned by the answer to the above StackOverflow answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I wanted. It's just the answer did not come up in my endless searching:

[Powershell select a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638927/powershell-select-a-specific-value)